# java.util.InputMismatchException errors in reading from file, what's wrong with type?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I'm learning from Java for Dummies and I don't know why I get these errors. I Googled some information.

`java.util.InputMismatchException` means that I want to read wrong type of values. For example file looks like:

```
2543
Robert
```

and I force the program to take from first line string.
In my opinion everything in my file look right. I compared my code to sample code in the book and I can't find any mistakes.

I use Netbeans.

The File "EmployeeInfo" look like this:

```
Angela 
nurse 
2000.23
```

The main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class DoPayroll {       
    public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException{
        Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner (new File("EmployeeInfo.txt"));
        payOneEmployee(diskScanner);
    }

    static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner)
    {
        Employee anEmployee = new Employee();

        anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine());
        anEmployee.SetJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine());
        anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble());
        aScanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The class:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;

    public void setName(String mName)
    {
        name = mName;
    }
    public String GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public  void SetJobTitle(String mJobTitle)
    {
        jobTitle =  mJobTitle;
    }
    public String GetJobTitle()
    {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void cutCheck(double amountPaid)
    {
        System.out.printf("Pay to the order of %s", name);
        System.out.printf("%s ***€", jobTitle);
        System.out.printf("%,.2f\n", amountPaid);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its due to the files contents...`EMPTY` scans fine (after Angela) and is pushed to setJobTitle. NextLine is `nurse` so nextDouble throws an input mismatch...just a guess

Comment: I want to show you that Angela, nurse and 2000.23 are in different lines, so I need to put the free line. It's connected with forum.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is related to netbeans?

Comment: I add this tag because I use this program.

Comment: Ok, comment out `aScanner.nextLine();` (last line in loop) from the method and run the program

Comment: yeah we wrote it in these same moment I think ;) thx for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like this also

```
static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner)
    {
        Employee anEmployee = new Employee();

        List<String> employeeValueList = new ArrayList();
        while (aScanner.hasNext())
        {
            employeeValueList.add(aScanner.next());
        }

        if (!employeeValueList.isEmpty())
        {
            anEmployee.setName(employeeValueList.get(0));
            anEmployee.SetJobTitle(employeeValueList.get(1));
            anEmployee.cutCheck(new Double(employeeValueList.get(2)));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine. I encountered the same problem with the Java for Dummies book.

For me, the problem lay within the formatting of the file. I am no expert (yet), so I am sorry to be unable to explain in further detail, but the `InputMismatchException` is thrown because I was using a `.` to separate the decimals while my system's standard decimals are separated by a `,`

I propose you try formatting your file like this:

```
Angela
nurse
2000,15
```

Answer (score 0):

if - EmployeeInfo.txt

---

Angela
nurse
2000.23

---

in the Code 
DoPayroll - class 
payOneEmployee -functions line no 4

anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine()); //  this line will take input - Angela
anEmployee.SetJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine()); // this will take zero input because second line dont have any data
    anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble()); // this line take input as - nurse 
//and "nurse" is not double so after reading this line at time of casting 
    from  nurse to duble it throw java.util.InputMismatchException